# If checkbox "A" and "C" is checked make checkbox "B" checked to

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

Hi there i have a problem and dont know if there's a nice solution to do that.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a">a<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b">b<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="c" value="c">c<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="d" value="c">d<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="e" value="c">e<br>
```

I like to make it work more as a "range" so if a user click "a" and then "d" everything between that will be selected to.

I can make if statements with all the scenarios but maybe there's a better way to do that?

thanks

Comment: native js? do you have jquery would make it easy

Comment: Did you try to code it? Or did you think of any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple with jQuery - use `prevAll` like so:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) this.prevAll('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```